# authentication with vue spa

Tags: authentication, vue.js, asp.net-core, vuejs2, single-page-application

I have followed a few guides on adding authentication to my vue application (which has a net core api backend).

https://medium.com/dev-bits/a-guide-for-adding-jwt-token-based-authentication-to-your-single-page-nodejs-applications-c403f7cf04f4

and

http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/08/14/aspnet-core-21-jwt-authentication-tutorial-with-example-api

I'm a junior programmer with authentication so forgive me if my questions seem dumb.

These involve sending a username and password to my api login method and getting back a jwt token (is this an id_token or an access token?). I then send this token with every api request using the Bearer authorization. Some guides (eg microsoft net core docs) have this jwt token include role information.

Is this just a basic form of jwt authentication. Some things i have read about token authentication indicate that when i login i should get an id token which i then exchange for an api access token. These tutorials don't appear to do that - it looks like there is only one token and that it's used for api access and authentication.

Ideally i would like to implement oidc into my vue application but the many guides out there dont seem to address this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorials are talking about the JWT token based authentication , it will issue a JWT token to declare a user and their access permissions in the application.

When a  user tries to log in to the application with their username and password, the server/api side will authenticate the user ,generate the token and send token back to client . Next time client could use token to access the server/API which eliminates the need for the app or system to remember or store the user’s credentials. You can involve user's basic profile information(not sensitive) and some custom claim in that token such as claim related to roles . Both client side and server side should check the specific role if you want to check the authorize part .

Id_token was added to the [OIDC specification](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken)(**OpenID Connect**) as an optimization so the application can know the identity of the user, without having to make an additional network requests. It contains user profile information (like the user's name, email, and so forth) , and  So if you are using **OpenID Connect** (Implicit Flow is suitable for SPA) to do the authentication and authorization , you will get id token which identity of the user , and access token which could be used to access the protected resource/API .

You are not using OpenID Connect , so no id token is involved in the scenario .

Comment: ok thanks - so which is better way - and by better i mean more secure. Is OpenIdConnect as easy to implement - would this require me to set up auth server such as IdentityServer?

Comment: @JimmyShoe . That is based on your requirement . OpenID connect usually is used to  make developers authenticate their users across websites and apps without having to own and manage password files . If you want the SSO feature , then use OpenID connect is good choice , it's easy to implement OIDC with authentication server like Identity Server or Azure AD , otherwise you need to write your own authentication server which is not easy to establish 。

Comment: Ok thanks, for now i will stick with jwt token authentication but may switch to using openconnectid in the future if I need to enable sso between my 2 applications.